Transitive npm dependency causing TS error
I have https://github.com/gorules/jdm-editor installed in my project. One of its dependencies is immer. When I run tsc --noEmit I get this TS6133 error:
npm run type-check

> my-ui@1.0.0 type-check
> tsc --noEmit

node_modules/immer/src/utils/common.ts:207:33 - error TS6133: 'key' is declared but its value is never read.

207   Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => freeze(value, true))
                                    ~~~

Found 1 error in node_modules/immer/src/utils/common.ts:207

From what I've read, this is because it's a transitive dependency so TypeScript is type-checking it as part of the dependency graph for jdm-editor.
If I install immer on its own, I have no TS error, which is why I think this has to do with it being a transitive dependency. How can I get TS to ignore this issue?
Here's my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "typeRoots": ["./src/@types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["./node_modules", "../typings"],
  "include": ["./src", "./vite.config.ts", "./jest.config.ts"]
}

Tried skipLibCheck false and true, with no change. Tried installing immer on its own and verified that it works fine solo. Tried pinning version of immer.

This question is similar to: How to force tsc to ignore node_modules folder?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'll specify here how it's different.
The first answer: "skipLibCheck": true didn't work (mentioned in my post already).

That question has 25 answers and 316 upvotes.  It's better to centralize the answers in one place.  You and others can still comment and answer there.

Sorry, hit enter as I was trying to make a list since I've gone through those already.
Adding an empty "types" option in "compilerOptions" didn't work. I'm on TS version 5.6.2, someone mentioned upgrading from 3.2.1 -> 3.7.3 so I don't think this is the same. My TS versions are in sync.
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"] doesn't fix. const immer = require('immer') CJS import won't work since this isn't directly imported in my project, it's transitive. "target": "ES2020", instead of esnext doesn't fix it, and"maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 0, doesn't fix it.

Thank you for doing your research.  Your question is still open, unless/until other community members vote to close it.
